# turn off auto-renaming of html elements' id in visual studio 2012

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

in the situation when i have conditional server code, visual studio keeps auto-renaming the duplicate id's.

here's a valid example:

```
<% if x = 1 then %>
<input type="hidden" id="hello" value=""/>
<% else %>
<input type="hidden" id="hello" value=""/>
<% end if %>
```

when visual studio's live error checking finds this, it will change my code without confirming with me to the following:

```
<% if x = 1 then %>
<input type="hidden" id="Hidden1" value=""/>
<% else %>
<input type="hidden" id="Hidden2" value=""/>
<% end if %>
```

how do i turn this off? i don't mind turning off the whole live error checking even. i don't know  where to toggle this "feature" though.

thank you for reading my question,

Comment: This is such an annoying Visual Studio feature.  I just wasted around 10 minutes hunting for a bug caused by this auto-rename-on-paste.  Typical of Microsoft to add a "feature" that's A) useless (the ids it assigns to your html elements are not DAMP - you need to go change them to something reasonable anyway) and B) gets in the way (in my case, by changing the behavior of Paste so that it no longer pastes what's in your clipboard).  </blowing-off-steam-with-inflammatory-remark>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into Tools -> Options

Scroll down to Text Editor. Expand it, then select HTML and expand it. Then click Miscellaneous and you should see the following.

[image]

Deselect the first option and try it.

Comment: thank you! it seems to work. it gives a squiggly line under the questionable duplicate id, but it doesn't automatically rename them now. :)

Comment: any idea where this went in VS2013.3?